# Angular : ng model array values got undefined in function on ng-click

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model, ng-bind

I am trying to allow users to add quantity into text box. I have products array and each product contains its property. My service contains array list.

```
products = [{
   id: 1,
   name: 'X Product',
   face: 'img/x_p.png',
   available_size: 6,
   color_available: 0,
   sizes: ['10"', '20"', '30"'],
   properties: [{size: '10"', mrp: '10$'},
              {size: '20"', mrp: '15$'},
              {size: '30"', mrp: '20$'}]
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   name: 'Y Product',
   face: 'img/y_p.png',
   available_size: 6,
   color_available: 0,
   sizes: ['10"', '20"', '30"'],
   properties: [{size: '10"', mrp: '10$'},
              {size: '20"', mrp: '15$'},
              {size: '30"', mrp: '20$'}]
}]
```

Iterating through the products array. When user clicks on product it will display a product show page. where I am showing all the information for the product. For properties I am showing a table where user can add their quantity just after each size.

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <h4>
    Product Detail
  </h4>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="tableHeader">
        <td>Size</td>
        <td>MRP</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="(key, property) in product.properties">
        <td>{{  property['size']  }}</td>
        <td>{{  property['mrp']  }}</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" placeholder="QTY" ng-model="qty">
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="button" ng-click="addToCart(property['size'], qty)">
        Add
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Question**: So according to this table each row contains a button with name add. So after adding quantity user clicks on add button will them allow to add item in cart. here I am getting size in *addToCart* function but got undefined qty as it should be an array with its respective size. Though I am getting size. But I don't know how to do that.

```
$scope.addToCart = function(size, qty) {
  alert($scope.qty)
}
```

I need a help.

Comment: you should alert(qty) and see if the parameter values are ok

Comment: @BorcheIvanov same result

Comment: I am getting size but not getting an qty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function() {
  this.addToCart = function(property, qty) {
    property["qty"] = qty;
  }
  this.product = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'X Product',
    face: 'img/x_p.png',
    available_size: 6,
    color_available: 0,
    sizes: ['10"', '20"', '30"'],
    properties: [{
      size: '10"',
      mrp: '10$'
    }, {
      size: '20"',
      mrp: '15$'
    }, {
      size: '30"',
      mrp: '20$'
    }]
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-bottom: 20px;" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
    <h4>
    Product Detail
  </h4>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="tableHeader">
          <td>Size</td>
          <td>MRP</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, property) in ctrl.product.properties">
          <td>{{ property['size'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ property['mrp'] }}</td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" placeholder="QTY" ng-model="qty">
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="button" ng-click="ctrl.addToCart(property, qty)">
        Add
          </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr/>
    {{ctrl.product.properties}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should I use ctrl or I can stick with my controller. I mean I am using my own controller then will this work or I can define with $scope?

Comment: You can use your controller, just define a variable (alias) fr it and use that, then you wont need `$scope`. See how i have ucreated the scope of `MyCtrl` and then used `ctrl.` notation

Comment: Great & very quick answer :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed many times that the textbox won't bind to a normal scope variable like

$scope.qty
 and binding it in view with  ng-model="qty"

Please try using something like

$scope.qty = {
   text:'   '
}

and bind it as  ng-model="qty.text" in the view

which will make sure that your textbox is actually bound.

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing to fix this issue: init qty by     $scope.qty = 0;